# Tuple Int error using python and sqlite

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

```
cur.execute("UPDATE statdata(threemonthreturn, twomonthreturn, maxonemonthreturn, avgonemonthreturn, lastweekreutrn) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE companyid=%s; ", (str(threemonthreturn), str(twomonthreturn), str(maxonemonthreturn), str(avgonemonthreturn), str(lastweekreturn)) %p)
```

I am having difficulties getting this line of code. Everything works fine Except the companyid=%s  and the %p.  I get this error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'int'

I have it in a loop where 'for p in range(1,72):'   and I have used it in a few previous lines of code with no problem. (the example below doesn't return an error)

```
 for p in range(1,72):
    cur.execute("SELECT (((onemonthmax - threemonthmin) / (onemonthmax))*100) FROM statdata WHERE companyid = %s" %p)
    threemonthreturn =cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Can someone help me with my placement of companyid=%s, %p  in the first line of code I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`cur.execute("UPDATE statdata(threemonthreturn, twomonthreturn, maxonemonthreturn, avgonemonthreturn, lastweekreutrn) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE companyid=?; ", (str(threemonthreturn), str(twomonthreturn), str(maxonemonthreturn), str(avgonemonthreturn), str(lastweekreturn),  p))`

The second argument to `execute` is a tuple: [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: I tried it, now I get this error

OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: The proper syntax for update is `update table_name set field1=value1,  ... where ...` so how about this: `cur.execute("UPDATE statdata set threemonthreturn=?, twomonthreturn=?, maxonemonthreturn=?, avgonemonthreturn=?, lastweekreutrn=?  WHERE companyid=? ", (str(threemonthreturn), str(twomonthreturn), str(maxonemonthreturn), str(avgonemonthreturn), str(lastweekreturn),  str(p)))`

Comment: forsure, do I just clock the up arrow?
How do I do this?
Nvm